# Why shouldn't a user cd to a directory using absolute path without rx to all its ancestors?

Tags: permissions, cd-command, acl

On Windows, it seems that if the user has read/write permission to the `lev5` directory, but no permission at all for all its ancestors,   `cd c:\lev1\lev2\lev3\lev4\lev5` still works.

On Linux, even if I give the user full permission to `lev5` and `rx` permission to `lev4` using `setfacl`, if he does not also have `rx` permissions for `lev1`/`lev2`/`lev3`, `cd /lev1/lev2/lev3/lev4/lev5` does not work.

**There is no way to make it work like Windows?**

One thing I noticed is that if the user's shell starts from `/lev1/lev2/lev3/lev4/` (the sudo user was in `/lev1/lev2/lev3/lev4/`, and switches to the user using `sudo -u` there, the user can `cd ./lev5`. For a moment, I wondered if this is a security feature to hide the existence of ancestor directories like `lev1` or `lev2` from the user (i.e., the user only knows `lev5` exists under `lev4` and nothing more), but that does not seem to be the case because executing `pwd` in the user's shell gives the full path `/lev1/lev2/lev3/lev4/lev5`, so I see no point of preventing the user from using full path `cd`.

Comment: I think that mentioned Windows privilege is called ["bypass traverse checking"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/bypass-traverse-checking) and I think it's configurable. You don't need `rx` access to the intermediate directories on Unixen either, just `x`. In effect, the `x` permission is the one that controls traversing to/through the directory, so if you make sure all directories have the `x` access bits set for everyone, you get the Windows behaviour.

Comment: @ilkkachu Is the `x` permission to a directory sort-of (I can't find a better expression) safe to give? I mean, if an untrusted user cannot do anything with just `x` other than navigating to a directory where he has the `r` permission, I would like to set `x` for all users to ALL directories by default (ACL is inheritable, right? so set `x` for everyone at `/` and then inherit).

Comment: they won't need the `r` permission to navigate to a directory. Just `x` is enough to access files within, you just can't read the listing of the filenames without the `r` permission. It does seem to me `x` in itself doesn't give much (except the possibility to enumerate filenames by trial and error), but I'm still not sure I'd go around granting it system-wide. At least directories that are supposed to be "private" to an extent or another (think e.g. `~/.ssh`, or heck, the home directories themselves), would be better off without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are essentially two ways of looking at something like `/lev1/lev2/lev3/lev4/lev5`, either as a single thing or as a sequence `/`, `lev1`, `lev2`, `lev3`, `lev4`, `lev5`. If you do the former then indeed there is no reason why you couldn't just require access to the object. However viewing it as a sequence and resolving it a step at a time allows you to do more sophisticated things. For example resolving a name might take you to some network storage. It is unreasonable to expect the OS on one machine to know the details of every single network storage device that could be connected so it could decide if you have rights to the eventual object.

Using `pwd` can be deceptive. It is frequently a builtin to the shell and is initialized from a `PWD` environment variable. In the old days `/bin/pwd` worked by changing to `..` and then looking in the current directory for something that matched where it had just been. It repeated this until it got to `/`. With that approach if you removed access in some parent directory you could get failures from `/bin/pwd`. These days on linux the kernel tracks where you are and all `/bin/pwd` does is call the `getcwd` system call.